AttributeError: 'DistributedDataParallel' object has no attribute 'policy' when saving a PPOTrainer
I am attempting to run a PPO script using Transformers and TRL.
However, I encounter an error during the model saving step:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/run/determined/workdir/main.py", line 247, in <module>
    main(training_args, det_callback, hparams)
  File "/run/determined/workdir/main.py", line 216, in main
    trainer.train()
  File "/run/determined/pythonuserbase/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/trainer/ppo_trainer.py", line 570, in train
    self._save_checkpoint(model, trial=None)
  File "/run/determined/pythonuserbase/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 3097, in _save_checkpoint
    self.save_model(output_dir, _internal_call=True)
  File "/run/determined/pythonuserbase/lib/python3.10/site-packages/trl/trainer/ppo_trainer.py", line 260, in save_model
    self.model = self.model.policy  # save only the policy
  File "/run/determined/pythonuserbase/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1931, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'DistributedDataParallel' object has no attribute 'policy'

The error is raised during the PPOTrainer training. Using this version or the v2 one raises the same error.
My code comes from the trl example here: https://github.com/huggingface/trl/blob/main/examples/scripts/ppo/ppo.py
def main(training_args, det_callback, model_config):

    ################
    # Model & Tokenizer
    ################

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        model_config["model_name_or_path"],
        padding_side="left",
        trust_remote_code=model_config["trust_remote_code"],
        #attn_implementation="flash_attention_2"
    )
    tokenizer.add_special_tokens({"pad_token": "[PAD]"})
    if tokenizer.chat_template is None:
        tokenizer.chat_template = SIMPLE_CHAT_TEMPLATE
    value_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        training_args.reward_model_path, trust_remote_code=model_config["trust_remote_code"], num_labels=1, #attn_implementation="flash_attention_2"
    )
    reward_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
        training_args.reward_model_path, trust_remote_code=model_config["trust_remote_code"], num_labels=1, #attn_implementation="flash_attention_2"
    )
    ref_policy = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        training_args.sft_model_path, trust_remote_code=model_config["trust_remote_code"], #attn_implementation="flash_attention_2"
    )
    policy = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        training_args.sft_model_path, trust_remote_code=model_config["trust_remote_code"], #attn_implementation="flash_attention_2"
    )
    ################
    # Dataset
    ################
    dataset = load_jsonl_dataset(model_config["dataset_name"], split=model_config["dataset_train_split"])
    eval_samples = 100
    dataset = dataset.filter(
        lambda example: sum(len(example[col]) for col in ['system', 'prompt', 'chosen', 'rejected']) < 4096 # lo so lo so, dovrei contare i token, ma va bene così per ora
    )
    train_dataset = dataset.select(range(len(dataset) - eval_samples))
    eval_dataset = dataset.select(range(len(dataset) - eval_samples, len(dataset)))
    dataset_text_field = "prompt"

    def prepare_dataset(dataset, tokenizer):
        """pre-tokenize the dataset before training; only collate during training"""

        def tokenize(element):
            outputs = tokenizer(
                element[dataset_text_field],
                padding=False,
            )
            return {"input_ids": outputs["input_ids"]}

        return dataset.map(
            tokenize,
            batched=True,
            remove_columns=dataset.column_names,
            num_proc=training_args.dataset_num_proc,
        )

    # Compute that only on the main process for faster data processing.
    # see: https://github.com/huggingface/trl/pull/1255
    with PartialState().local_main_process_first():
        train_dataset = prepare_dataset(train_dataset, tokenizer)
        eval_dataset = prepare_dataset(eval_dataset, tokenizer)

    ################
    # Training
    ################
    
    trainer = PPOTrainer( # PPOTrainer( PPOv2Trainer
        config=training_args,
        processing_class=tokenizer,
        policy=policy,
        ref_policy=ref_policy,
        reward_model=reward_model,
        value_model=value_model,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    )

    trainer.train()

I'm trying this function on a Llama based model.
I've got no idea of what the problem could be...
I thank you for any advice you can give me!
EDIT: Add more details here: https://github.com/huggingface/trl/issues/2375
